# How do we share vue modal between micro UIs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, v-model

I have a Home app H which has multiple individual UIs A, B, C etc(used single spa). I have a v-modal which is created in UI A, now I'm looking for a way to open the same v-modal from UI B. Is there a way to achieve this use case?

vue: 2.6.11

Comment: You can add the v-modal globally outside the routing scope(SPA). Then you can trigger emits to open and close from inside any child component.

Comment: Like this? https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-ellis-kmni6e

Comment: @Lissy93 -  Thank you. But here A, B, & C are not components but there are different applications. So, I need to access application A's component C from application B. Here I'm looking the solution without moving the component C from  application A.

Comment: In that case, you'd need to extract the component out of application A, and have it as a standalone plugin (maybe an NPM module), then you can use it across each app